# Extracting a complex type from entry.CurrentValues

Tags: entity-framework-5

Some of my domain classes contain a complex type for a street address.
I am capturing a log of my changes, and want to be able to reconstruct the address object from the ObjectStateEntry.CurrentValues

My code is detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19748112/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-data-objects-objectstateentrydbupdatabledat)

And I want to extract the address from CurrentValues as the answer suggests.

I can see the address in the  _userObject property in the debugger, but i don't know how to extract it.

I have tried

```
var obj = entry.CurrentValues[ordinal];
var rec = (DbDataRecord)obj;
```

what should be next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public static T ConvertTo<T>(this DbDataRecord record)
    {
        T item = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        for (int f = 0; f < record.FieldCount; f++)
        {
            var p = item.GetType().GetProperty(record.GetName(f));
            if (p != null && p.PropertyType == record.GetFieldType(f))
            {
                p.SetValue(item, record.GetValue(f), null);
            }
        }

        return item;
    }
```